# Decide whether $f(x)$ is diff on $(-1,1)$ and integrable on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Here I have two piecewise functions;

$$f_1(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1  & x = 0 \\
             \\ 0 & x \in \mathbb{R}, x \not= 0 \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

$$f_2(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1  & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
             \\ 0 & x \in \mathbb{R}  \text{not including}  \mathbb{Q} \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

and i want to know if these two functions:

$1)$ $f$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$

$2)$ $f$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$

what i'm asking sounds really simple but I don't think i have fully understood the definition of integral and differentiability yet and i'm having a hard time. I have read chapters about partition to understand integrability on spivak's book where it states, $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if it is bounded on $[a,b]$ and sup{L(f,P)} = inf{U(f,P)} i.e. $L(f,P) \le $ $\int_a^b f \le U(f,P)$ My guess is that for $f_1(x)$ it is both diff and integrable on $(-1,1)$ and $[-1,1]$ respectively but im not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neither $f_1$ nor $f_2$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$ since they are discontinuous at $x=0$.

$f_1$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$ since it has exactly one discontinuity.

$f_2$ is not integrable, all the upper sums are $1$ and all the lower sums are $0$, for every partition.